# Calculating COGS to finish stock balance report SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two source table as following: Purchase & Sale

```
               purchase (incoming)
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------
 inventory_id | quantity | price |  Amount  |  timestamp 
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------
 A            |        1 | $1.00 |   $1.00  |  2020-02-01
 B            |        2 | $1.00 |   $2.00  |  2020-02-02
 C            |        4 | $2.00 |   $8.00  |  2020-02-03
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------


               sale (outgoing)
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------
 inventory_id | quantity | price |  Revenue |  timestamp
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------
 A            |        1 | $3.00 |   $3.00  |  2020-02-04
 B            |        1 | $3.00 |   $3.00  |  2020-02-05
 C            |        2 | $3.00 |   $6.00  |  2020-02-05
 C            |        1 | $3.00 |   $3.00  |  2020-02-07
--------------+----------+-------+----------+--------------
```

What I want to do is the balance report in the below format:

```
               Balance Report (2020-02-02 to 2020-02-05)
--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+
 inventory_id | Begin Qty | Begin Amount| Purchase Qty|Purchase Amount|  Sale Qty | COGS Amount | End Qty | End Amount |
--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+
 A            |         1 |     $1.00   |             |               |     1     |    $1.00   |         |            |
 B            |           |             |      2      |      $2.00    |     1     |    $1.00   |  $1.00  |   $1.00    |
 C            |           |             |      4      |      $8.00    |     2     |    $4.00   |  $2.00  |   $4.00    |
--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+---------+------------+

Note: The last outgoing transaction is out of the Report time range (2-05/02/2020) then not showing on the report.
```

MY CURRENT SOLUTION:

- Add one column 'COGS' in the Sale table
- I have to calculate the COGS of all inventory_id in the current sale order
- Then save the COGS to the server with other information of sale order

THE PROBLEM:

If there is any change of the past transactions in the Purchase or Sale order, the COGS column does not UPDATE.

I NEED HELP ON:

- Case 1: Keep COGS Column in the Sale table

How to update the value in this column if pasts transactions changed?

- Case 2: Remove COGS Column

Pls help me to write a query to calculate the Sale Amount column in the Balance Report (Moving average is ok)

It would be great if you could provide the query to calculate the Sale Amount column by FIFO, LIFO.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which RDBMS and why not have one source table, instead of two?

Comment: And what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Primary key is Inventory_id
And I am using MS SQL sever.

There are Some columns exist in Sale but not in Purchase, so i want to split them into TWO table then it is to expand and update.

Comment: *"I am using MS SQL server"* then please don't tag other RDBMS, it only makes the question harder to answer. I have removed [tag:mysql] from the question.

Comment: Inventory_id is not unique.

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Help me" isn't an answerable question. Show us what you have, and then tell us why that isn't working. Then we can help you by explaining what's wrong with that attempt and how to correct it.

Comment: In the Inventory list the Inventory_ID is unique for Sure.

We call the inventory_id form inventory list to make the balance report

Comment: Why there is a sales qty for `C` when you stated the date is until `2020-02-05` ?

Comment: The purchase of A and both sales of C are not within the timespan as well...

Comment: Purchase of `A` is fine. It contributed to the Begin Qty of 1. Inconsistency is on the `C`

Comment: But I guess there are other glitches in the desired output: the sale of A ocurrs later than the purchase of B or C... so the calculation of EndQty etc. doesn't make sense here. Except if you calculate BeginbQty etc. per InvID

Comment: Why there is a sales qty for C when you stated the date is until 2020-02-05 => Sorry for the mistake, I already correct

Comment: How do you get to your "Sale Amount 1.00" for Inv. B ins the expected output if the Sale-Line hast amound and price 3.00?

Comment: @Tyron78 , I have corrected the title SaleAmount in the Sale Table and Balance Report to avoid misunderstanding. Thanks for your respone

Comment: @hungrycode but still something seems odd: Sticking with Qty for the time being to make the example easier to follow, you start with Inv A having beginQty 1 and you sell 1 which would lead to endQty 0. Then you have Inv B with purch 2 and sale 1 which leads to 0 (from A) + 2 (purch B) -1 (sale B) giving endQty 1. Now you have inv C with purch 4 and sale 2, which would lead to 1 (endQty of B) + 4 (purch C) - 2 (sale C) = 3 but you expect endQty 2 for inv C... additionally I think the inconsistency concerning the prices is confusing. inv A has price 1, inv C has 2, the sales have price 3...

Comment: @tyron78 Something misunderstanding here. "Then you have Inv B with purch 2 and sale 1 which leads to 0 (from A) + 2 (purch B) -1 (sale B) giving endQty 1" => EndQty based on Inventory_id, not culmulated from one to another.

Comment: @Tyron78 The formula is: EndQty of A = BeginQty of A + PurQty of A - SaleQty of A. End; EndAmount of A = BeginAmount of A + PurAmount of A - COGS of A. The COGS of each Inventory_id: = Moving average price * SaleQty

Comment: @hungrycode OK, but why does your expected output not feature any begin values for Inv B and C?

Comment: @hungrycode and by the way: from where did you get the begin values of A? If you consider the first purchase per Inv as begin value, you have only begin - sale left, since each inv in your example features only one purchase. Furthermore inv B and C would have begin values as well and no purchases whatsoever... or is the source of the begin values another table (such as the inventory table)? In this case please add the inventory table to your example

Comment: @Tyron78, for this case i want to simply the request then only need the Purchase and Sale table as the sources to calculate the Balance report. The Begin of Any Inv_id  = Purchase before begin date - Sale before begin date.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: "I need to update COGS unit price for every transaction"

Following is the main code to update COGS

You might need to change something to adapt your case.

I know it is not the best solution but for my case it is ok.

```
create procedure update_COGS
as
 update Sale
    set
        Sale.price = b.Aprice
    from
        Sale a
        left join (select code, SUM(quantity) as quantity, sum(amount) as amount, SUM(amount)/nullif(sum(quantity),0) as Aprice from Purchase  group by code) b
        on a.code = b.code
```